# LDAP authorization

Tags: authentication, ldap, authorization, roles, security-roles

I'm starting to implement authorization and authentication mechanism using LDAP, for some existing system. On the development stage, I'm facing a difficult design decision: **where should user roles be stored?**

If I used RDBMS, it looks like there will be three tables: **user**, **role** and **user_role** to map roles and users.

Please suggest available solutions. I think about storing the user roles in DB and users in LDAP, but not sure if that is the best solutions. I use JBoss as my application server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the architectural point of view, you've got multiples solutions. Here is a solution that keeps all your data into a Directory.

In your Directory you can code your 'Roles' with objects from a class with the meaning of "group" like `groupOfNames` or `group` (depending on you Directory). Users Distinguisched Names (DN) will them be coded in a multivalued attribute of these objects (generally `member`). The 'Role' object DN can be, in return, coded in a multivalued attribute of the user object (Ex : `memberof`)

In the case your Directory support referential integrity, it can act as a system Directory. Then `member` and `memberOf` attributes can be managed by the Directory itself. This mean that if you move a user from an Organizational Unit to an other one, the Directory is going refresh the `member` attribute of the 'Role' objects the user belongs to.

In the other case (no referencial integrity) your application has to manage the attribute integrity.

It's short but I hope it help.

---

Edited

Thirst off all I recomend you [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/) , that is (for me) one of the best LDAP Browser. tHis tool will allow you to see your Directory and to learn LDAP more freindly. Using this tool I show you the way ADAM (Active Directory Application Mode) the free Directory of Microsoft code the 'Roles'

In the first picture you can see AdminAdam as a member of the administrators group :

[image: AdminAdam as a member of the administrators group]

In this second picture, you can see the presence of the group in the attribute memberof of the user adminAdam.

[image: the attribute memberof of the user adminAdam]

ADAM is suporting referencial Integrity.

Comment: Great. What about permission for the Role? must I follow in the same way. I afraid that I'll take really difficult structure in result. What do you think? Thanks again!