# OBIEE LDAP authorization

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap, authorization, obiee

I have a question similiar to [LDAP authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246030/ldap-authorization) but more specifically to OBIEE and Microsoft AD.

As described in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12211/bip/BIPAD/GUID-B08E067E-0B67-46C0-8F0B-6DB752681950.htm), if I use BI Publisher I only need to create a couple of XMLP_% roles in Active Directory and grant them to users after AD authentication is set up.

My questions are:

1. Can I use similiar approach to using Analytics?
2. Am I obligated to use external store for user roles?
3. Can I use DefaultAthenticator provider for roles and grant them to Active Directory users?
4. I want to use existing tools only if possible. Which options do I have for storing roles apart from database tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create anything inside the AD at all. You just map whatever AD groups you want to OBI application roles.

DefaultAuthenticator is the WLS-embedded LDAP. Leave that alone, otherwise you lock out your "weblogic" admin account.

Comment: Oh... OH!... You just map them! Ahah, I'm so dumb, thank you! :)

Comment: No worries. If you want a complete overview, I held a workshop on that a while ago:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUCZwQOmBn8

Comment: Yes I do, please :) Thanks again!